# Intercept button click on page load

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, delegates, event-handling

I need to write a code that can intercept a click of some button (asp button) than execute some code, and if a method return true, call the original click.

So the points are:

1- I don´t know how to save the original click.

2- Identify the button that was clicked.

Ex:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var b = getButtonThatWasClicked();

        var originalClick = b.Click;

        if(callSomeMethod(b))
            originalClick(null,null);
    }
```

EDIT:

Ok managed to get the button who made the click doing this...Now i need to prevent the original Click to get called. The method bellow didn't worked. Even overriding the original click to a new Handler the old Handler got called and executed. I thing ASP.NET read it and make something like a call stack of events to get called.Even if the handler change the old still in the stack.

```
    public void ButtonsTestMethod()
    {
        var listOfButtons = listaDeBotes.Where(b => b.CommandName != "");

        foreach (var button in listOfButtons)
        {
            if (Request.Form[button.UniqueID] != null)
            {
                var buttonFromRequest = Request.Form[button.UniqueID];
                if (buttonFromRequest == null)
                    continue;

                if (button.CommandName != "xxx")
                { 
                    //validate things
                    //if(TemPermissao(Tela,GetAcaoDoBotao(botao.CommandName)))
                    //if(!canexecuteSomething())
                    button.Click += new EventHandler(defaultClick);   
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void defaultClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //show error
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //other code
        ButtonsTestMethod();
    }
```

I don´t know if its possible but would appreciate some help =/

Thanks.

Comment: Why not let the original click be handled and do the check on the very first line to see if it should continue executing or just return immediately?

Comment: `sender` is, or should be, a reference to the originator of the [postback|click] event. Meaning it should be the control itself. As noted, though: why not handle each control's click event appropriately? You can still factor out the common code and keep it DRY.

Comment: The point is: stop the click before it reached the original Click event. And not add a line on the ever button Click method handler.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the control name, you can try the following in the page load:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if( IsPostBack ) 
    {
        string senderControl = Request.Params["__EVENTTARGET"].ToString();
        //senderControl will contain the name of the button/control responsible for PostBack
    }
  }
```

Comment: its not providing sender control for button click

Answer (score 0):

The first argument in the button click event handler is the sender. You can cast that sender as a `Button` object and then you should be able to identify which button that was based on that object. That way, you can eliminate having that function to figure out which is clicked.

```
void GreetingBtn_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button clickedButton = (Button)sender;
    if(clickedButton.Text == "bla")
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Right.I know that.but i need a way to that withought do on every button and execute the fuction. that code must act behind the scenes...before the button click get called

Comment: If you need to handle this before the click action is called, you should wire up a javascript click event handler.   You can then either perform your logic in Javascript, or perform an Ajax request to process on the server.  Return false from the click handler if you do not want to proceed.

Comment: Well..that could work.but would need an additional request what i'am trying at least for now, to avoid.thanks by the way